# React Use state doesn't upload variabe

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, use-state

I'm trying to create an uploading system for my website and i have an issue. When i try to load my file information using react states, my variable image doesn't update.

```
const [titolo, setTitolo] = useState("")
const [image, setImage] = useState([])
const [descrizione, setDescrizione] = useState("")
const [prezzo, setPrezzo] = useState("")
const [quantita, setQuantita] = useState(0)

const fileSelectedHandler = event  => {
  console.log(event.target.files[0])
  setImage(event.target.files[0])
  console.log(image)
}
```

So when i console log the event.target.files[0] it appears to me this:
[Reults of console.log(event.target.files[0])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rlmu.png)

But when i print my image variable it seems like this:
[Result of console.log(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8swZ1.png)

So when i ty with axios to pass my file information i didn't have any information. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect `image` to be console logged right after `setImage(...)` function call due to the async nature of JavaScript. You should add a `useEffect` hook as below.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(image)
  }, [image]);
```

Comment: Just call ``Axios.post(...your parameters for file uplaod...)`` instead of console.log inside the ``useEffect`` hook.

Comment: @Lume, if this fixes your problem, please mark this as the answer. Thanks!